# Yii 2 RESTful API authenticate with OAuth2 (Yii 2 advanced template)

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

REST API is working without authentication methods. Now i wanted to authenticate REST API with OAuth2  authentication for API requests via mobile application. I tried with yii2 guide, but it didn't work for me.

basically mobile user need to be login with username & password, if a username and password are correct, user need to be login and further API request need to be validate with token.

Do i need to create custom OAuth 2 client like this ?
[Creating your own auth clients](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-authclient-index.html#creating-your-own-auth-clients)

access_token field in user table is empty. do i need to save it manually ? 
how to return access_token as a respond?

is there any reason for user all three methods(HttpBasicAuth, HttpBearerAuth, QueryParamAuth) at once, why? how?

my application folder structure looks like below.

```
api
-config
-modules
--v1
---controllers
---models
-runtime
-tests
-web

backend
common
console
environments
frontend
```

api\modules\v1\Module.php

```
namespace api\modules\v1;
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\modules\v1\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init(); 
        \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;       
    }   
}
```

api\modules\v1\controllers\CountryController.php

```
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use common\models\User;
use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;

/**
 * Country Controller API
 *
 * @author Budi Irawan <deerawan@gmail.com>
 */
class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Country';    

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            //'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBasicAuth::className(),
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                QueryParamAuth::className(),
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

}
```

common\models\User.php

```
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {

        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }


}
```

user table

```
id
username
auth_key
password_hash
password_reset_token
email
status
created_at
access_token
```

access_token was added after migrate user table

Comment: did you came across with a solution?

Comment: access_token must be generatet manually (for example, sha1(uniqid())). Basically, after login (username & password) user recieved access token, and use it in one of three methods(HttpBasicAuth, HttpBearerAuth, QueryParamAuth) in every other request to server.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using JWT for validating the request. Basically JWT is a token which also contain information about a user, and about the token itself such as the validity and the expiration time of the token. You can read more about JWT [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

The flow of my application is like this:

- First, when a user logged in, create a JWT for the user

  ```
  $key = base64_decode('some_random_string');

  $tokenId = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(32));
  $issuedAt = time();
  $notBefore = $issuedAt + 5;
  $expire = $notBefore + 1800;

  $user = User::findByEmail($email);

  $data = [
      'iss' => 'your-site.com',
      'iat' => $issuedAt,
      'jti' => $tokenId,
      'nbf' => $notBefore,
      'exp' => $expire,
      'data' => [
          'id' => $user->id,
          'username' => $user->username,
          //put everything you want (that not sensitive) in here
      ]
  ];

  $jwt = JWT::encode($data, $key,'HS256');

  return $jwt;
  ```
- Then, the client (e.g the mobile app) must provide the token in every request via Authorization header. The header will look like this:

  `Authorization:Bearer [the JWT token without bracket]`
- In the User model, add a method like this for validating the token:

  ```
  public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
      $key = base64_decode('the same key that used in login function');

      try{
          $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
          return static::findByEmail($decoded->data->email);
      }catch (\Exception $e){
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

  The JWT library will raise an Exception if the token is no longer invalid (have been tampered or have been past the expiry time).
- Then, add this to the behaviors function in every controller:

  ```
  $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
      'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
      'except' => ['login'] //action that you don't want to authenticate such as login
  ];
  ```

That's it! I hope this work like you wanted. Oh, and there is lot of JWT libraries that you can use (you can see it [here](https://jwt.io/#libraries)), but I personally use [this library by people from firebase](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

Answer (score 1):

You Can create Your Auth System, usually I do it.
You can Save Tokens for every user, and after it authentify user by that token.
In every action You can send that token for authentify user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

- set the token before saving the user in the User model.
- add actionLogin in the UserController to return the auth_key on user login.
- in each API request you send the auth_key in the header instead of
  sending username and password.
- to check if the auth_key is valid, define 'authenticator' in the
  UserController behaviors.

you can find code samples in my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880518/yii-2-restful-api-authenticate-with-http-basic-yii-2-advanced-template/32135758#32135758)